# Queries in Hazerlcast

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I have a Map that uses MapStore. In this way, some objects are not loaded into Memory. How I can search a required object if it isn't in memory?
Is 'read-through' feature working for queries?

Comment: Where does the MapStore get the data ? It may be possible currently or soon, depending on what the data is sourced from.

Comment: well ... could you please take details? Where it is possible?
I am using MongoDB as MapStore.

Answer (score 0):

You can query Hazelcast for data held in Hazelcast or for data external to Hazelcast using the same SQL,
`SELECT * FROM etc..`

For the latter, see [documentation link](https://jet-start.sh/docs/sql/ddl#create-and-drop-external-mapping).

Unfortunately, there is not currently an implementation for Mongo. So for now you are blocked, sorry.

*Read-through* (or *query-through*) would also require the remote store have the same format as the IMap, which is not otherwise required for MapStore.

If you can't host all your Mongo data in Hazelcast (which eliminates the need to query Mongo), then you could perhaps consider some sort of fly-weight design pattern and perhaps hold a projection.